# Why isn't HTML Entity in input title not working for React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Why can't I use the HTML Entity `&le;` for the HTML input title attribute using a JavaScript constant but I can if I use a string?

The HTML Entity `&le;` is the ≤ symbol.

I have provided a demonstration:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-1ji67?file=/index.js:256-260

When you hover over the top input, you'll see the symbol which was defined by a string. However, if you hover over the bottom input, the symbol is not displayed instead the string `&le;` which was defined using a const.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You need to be in a JSX context to emit ≤, not just a string.

You may need to use `<></>` instead of `<React.Fragment></React.Fragment>` or a `<div>` / `<span>` would also work.

Comment: This is also covered in the old React documentation: https://shripadk.github.io/react/docs/jsx-gotchas.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use `parseFromString()` method converting to html from string by declaring `DOMParser()`. Like this

```
const pars = new DOMParser();
const tooltip = pars.parseFromString("0 &le; 5", 'text/html').body.textContent;
```

Ultimately specifies a decorated constant:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const pars = new DOMParser();
    const tooltip = pars.parseFromString("0 &le; 5", 'text/html').body.textContent;
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <label>Working tooltip: </label>
        <input type="text" title="0 &le; 5" />
        <br />
        <label>Not working tooltip: </label>
        <input type="text" title={tooltip} />
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("container"));
```